# Translate Salesforce Standard functionality in to other language

Tags: customer-portal, translation, customlabel, workbench

Here i am use customer portal.And want to translate whole customer portal into other language like german,french,spanish,etc.I cover custom functionality with the help of custom label,workbench translation,etc.

Here i have problem with some of the standard functionality that is not automatically translated.please see the below snapshot

[image]

As per Above red mark portion is a one kind of standard functionality...

1) picklist value "All" was not translated in customer portal as per specific login language.

2) And "Go" button title is not traslated in customer portal as per specific login language.

For that i am also try in workbench translation custom button and picklist value,but that was not translated.

so here what can i do please some one help me to translate this portion into specified login language.

Comment: RE: List View names, it does not look like this is currently supported, see this idea and vote on it here, https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrsCAAS

Comment: RE: Go!, this looks like an odd label for the typically list view button, is the page your showing a Visualforce page or standard one?

Comment: Here is a list of supported items for Translation Workbench, again, sadly List View is not one them, http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176742&language=en_US

Comment: thanks for your answer...that's the standard page..but it is the standard functionality..most of standard functionality translated except that rounded red marked portion....

Comment: Then i would say if its a standard Salesforce button, it's a bug that its not translated and should be raised with Salesforce. THe ListView translation, is a known limitation it seems, best you can do is upvote the idea and follow it.

Comment: No problem, i've written up our conclusions as an answer to this question for future readers. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly **Translation Workbench** [does not support List Views](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176742&language=en_US) it seems, though there is a Idea to vote for this to be added [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrsCAAS). As regards the Go! button, as per our discussion above, if this is truly a standard Salesforce page, then this to me appears to be a bug and should be raised as a case with Salesforce.